# Reading csv files to send discrete pdf files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pdf

I am pretty new at Python. I am trying to make it so I can open a csv and if the last name of the csv matches with the last name of a pdf file, it automatically sends to that email address.

The reason for this is I have to send about 150 pay stubs to people every two weeks, and I know there has to be a way to automate it. I've found several places that show how to read through a csv file, it's the reading and matching pdf files where I am struggling.

This is what I have so far.  There are definitely a few errors.

```
    import smtplib, ssl
    from email import encoders
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465

    sender = "@@@gmail.com"
   password = input("enter password here")
   receiver = "testtest@gmail.com"

    message = MIMEMultipart("Multipart Test")
    message['Subject'] = 'Pay stub'
    message['From'] = sender
   message['To'] = receiver

    text = """\

    Hey,

    Here is your pay stub.  If you have any corrections please let me know ASAP.

    Thanks
    """

    html= """\
     <html>
        <body>
            <p>Hey,
            Here is your pay stub.  If you have any corrections please let me know ASAP.

    Thanks
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

     filename="cg_email"

    with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
        part_a = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part_a.set_payload(attachment.read()

    encoders.encode_base64(part_a)
    part_a.add_header(
        'Content Disposition',
        f'attachment; filename={filename}'
     )

    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)
    message.attach(part_a)

    context= ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I make it so I can read off a csv and send discrete pdf files to each employee with their information.

For example I want to be able to read off the csv Bob Smith, then have the script look at the email address, and then find the corresponding pdf file then email it to Bob Smith.

Comment: What have you tried _to do the thing that you want to do_? Your question seems to be about reading from CSV files, your example is for sending an email.

Comment: Right, I want to read from a csv file, match the last name in the csv file with the corresponding last name of the pdf file, and then I want it to send an email with the pdf attached to the stored email in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get what exactly it is that you want to do, but for reading a csv file you can try following code

Assuming CSV contains Data as

[image]

[In]

```
#to read CSV Files 
dr = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv')) 

#getting Columns
columns = dr.fieldnames

#reading row records one by one
for r in dr.reader:
    # To create a dictionary with column_names as keys and row cells values as values
    record = dict(zip(columns, r)) 
    print(record)
    
    print('FileName: ', record['FileName'])
    print('FilePath: ', record['FilePath'])
```